# asyncio CancelledError and KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying 2 ways to stop an infinite loop from running:

- **supervisor_1**: task is canceled programatically
- **supervisor_2**: task is stopped with Ctrl+C

While **supervisor_2** does not throw any errors at when interrupted, I cannot get **supervisor_1** from getting `Task was destroyed but it is pending!`. Any idea why ?

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import aioredis
from functools import partial



class Listener:
    def __init__(self, redis_conn):
        self.redis_conn = redis_conn

    async def forever(self, loop_name):
        counter = 0
        try:
            while True:
                print('{}: {}'.format(loop_name, counter))
                counter += 1
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print('Task Cancelled')
            self.redis_conn.close()
            await self.redis_conn.wait_closed()


async def supervisor_1(redis_conn):
    redis_conn = await redis_conn

    l = Listener(redis_conn)

    task = asyncio.ensure_future(
        asyncio.gather(l.forever('loop_1'), 
                       l.forever('loop_2')))
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    task.cancel()


async def supervisor_2(redis_conn):
    redis_conn = await redis_conn

    l = Listener(redis_conn)
    await asyncio.gather(l.forever('loop_1'), 
                         l.forever('loop_2'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    redis_conn = aioredis.create_pool(('localhost', 5003), db=1)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    run = partial(supervisor_2, redis_conn=redis_conn)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interruped !')
        task.cancel()
        loop.run_forever()
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

**@update**:

Thanks to @Gerasimov, here is a version that fix the problem, but somehow still raise errors from time to time on KeyboardInterrupt:

```
async def supervisor(redis_conn):
    redis_conn = await redis_conn

    l = Listener(redis_conn)

    task = asyncio.ensure_future(
        asyncio.gather(l.forever('loop_1'), 
                       l.forever('loop_2'))
    )
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task

async def kill_tasks():
    pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()
        with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
            await task
```

and

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    redis_conn = aioredis.create_pool(('localhost', 5003), db=1)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    run = partial(supervisor, redis_conn=redis_conn)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interruped !')
        loop.run_until_complete(kill_tasks())
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`task.cancel()` itself doesn't finish the task: it just says to task that `CancelledError` should be raised inside it and returns immediately. You should call it and await while task would be actually cancelled (while it'll raise `CancelledError`).

You also shouldn't suppress `CancelledError` inside task.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) where I tried to show different ways of working with tasks. For example to cancel some task and await it cancelled you can do:

```
from contextlib import suppress


task = ...  # remember, task doesn't suppress CancelledError itself

task.cancel()  # returns immediately, we should await task raised CancelledError.

with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
    await task  # or loop.run_until_complete(task) if it happens after event loop stopped

# Now when we awaited for CancelledError and handled it, 
# task is finally over and we can close event loop without warning.
```

Comment: thanks for the link. I updated my answer with what I understood of a fix. But still getting errors (however not always like before)

Comment: @Orelus, same error as before? Try to move `loop.run_until_complete(kill_tasks())` into finally block, just before `loop.close()`. This should probably solve problem. I'm not sure what your `run()` coroutine do, but probably situation can happen, when it finished, but some tasks are not: in that case on closing event loop you'll get warning even if no `KeyboardInterrupt` happened.

Comment: Note a downside to using this approach: if the calling task is itself cancelled while it is waiting for the child task to clean up and exit, the `suppress()` call will swallow *that* `CancelledError` instead and, in fact, the `await task` could be aborted early.  It looks like current asyncio (as of 3.8 at least) may have no way to avoid this.