# Thread and asyncio: Task was destroyed but it is pending

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a thread that runs an asyncio loop. I start a future task that does things which are irrelevant here. When I stop the thread, I stop the asyncio loop as well. However, I cannot seem to cancel the pool task and get `Task was destroyed but it is pending!`

Here is a toy example:

```
from contextlib import suppress
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import asyncio


class Hardware(Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Hardware, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loop = None
        self._poll_task = None

    def run(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
        self.loop.create_task(self._poll())
        self.loop.run_forever()

    async def _poll(self):
        print('ook')
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        self._poll_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._poll())
        return self._poll_task

    def stop(self):
        if self._poll_task is not None:
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self._poll_task.cancel)
        with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)


hw = Hardware()
try:
    hw.start()
    while True:
        sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    hw.stop()
    hw.join()
```

Running it outputs:

```
; python ook.py
ook
ook
^CTask was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Hardware._poll() running at ook.py:22> wait_for=<Future cancelled>>
```

*What am I doing wrong?*

Comment: I refactored code a bit for nicer starting/shutdowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not only call `cancel()` on task, but also [await its cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810272/1113207) instead of just stopping loop as you do.

```
from contextlib import suppress
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import asyncio


class Hardware(Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loop = None
        self._poll_task = None

    def run(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        loop = self.loop
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        try:
            # create task:
            self._poll_task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._poll())

            # run loop:
            loop.run_forever()
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())

            # cancel task:
            self._poll_task.cancel()
            with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
                loop.run_until_complete(self._poll_task)
        finally:
            loop.close()

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)

    async def _poll(self):
        while True:  # you don't need to create new task each time
            print('ook')
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)


hw = Hardware()
try:
    hw.start()
    while True:
        sleep(.1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    hw.stop()
    hw.join()
```