# asyncio task cancel. Is is synchronous?

Tags: python, event-loop, python-asyncio

I understand that `task.cancel()` arranges an exception to be thrown inside the task function. Is that happen in a synchronous way? (As I don't await task.cancel()). Can code that follows the line `task.cancel()` assume that the task will no longer run?

A simple example:

```
async def task1():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("after sleep")

async def task2():
    t = loop.create_task(task1())
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    t.cancel()
    # can the following code lines assume that task1 is no longer running?

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: From reading the documentation I would say no, it says "This arranges for a CancelledError exception to be thrown into the wrapped coroutine on the next cycle of the event loop."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can code that follows the line task.cancel() assume that the task will
>   no longer run?

No. `task.cancel()` only marks task to be cancelled later. You should explicitly await task after it and catch `CancelledError` to be sure task is cancelled.

See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810272/1113207).