# calrifications about asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to wrap my head around python asyncio.

```
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio


def print_time(number, loop):
    et = loop.time() + 10.0
    while True:
        print('loop {} time {}'.format(number, datetime.now()))
        if (loop.time() >= et):
            break
        yield from asyncio.sleep(3)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

asyncio.ensure_future(print_time(1,loop))
asyncio.ensure_future(print_time(2,loop))

loop.run_forever()
```

The output (from Jupyter notebook)

```
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 21:38:47.398280
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 21:38:47.398452
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 21:38:50.401818
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 21:38:50.402335
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 21:38:53.405770
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 21:38:53.406243
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 21:38:56.409524
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 21:38:56.410034
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 21:38:59.413300
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 21:38:59.413846
```

I have the following questions about the above program

1. In this case is the function `print_time` considered a coroutine (as in contains `yield` statement?
2. does ensure_future() creates a separate task/process each time it is called? In that sense is it analogous to fork()
3. The current loop is running for ever. How do I gracefully exit after say 10 iterations.?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In this case is the function print_time considered a coroutine (as in contains yield statement?

You can create coroutine from function when you need it (for example, if it should await another coroutine). To [create](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#tasks-and-coroutines) coroutine you should use special decorator `@asyncio.coroutine` (or define coroutine with `async def` in Python 3.5+):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def print_time(number, loop):
    ...
```

In your case generator considered as coroutine only because asyncio's coroutines implemented using generators. You shouldn't use regular generators as coroutines, instead you should always explicitly use decorator `@asyncio.coroutine` (or `async def`) to create coroutines.

> 2. does ensure_future() creates a separate task/process each time it is called? In that sense is it analogous to fork()

`ensure_future` doesn't create OS thread or process. Usually all your coroutines/tasks run in single OS thread, single process.

`ensure_future` is a way to rule flow of execution your async script. When you just await for some coroutine, code below it would be run only after coroutine finished. `ensure_future` allows you to ["run coroutine in background"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) without blocking code below it from execution.

Example 1:

```
yield from coro_1()
yield from coro_2()  # this line would be started only after coro_1 finished.
```

Example 2:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(coro_1())
yield from coro_2()  # this line would be started immediately.
                     # coro_1 and coro_2 would de facto run parallely.
```

> 3. The current loop is running for ever. How do I gracefully exit after say 10 iterations.?

You have many ways to do it, depending of how you want your code to work.

Here's one, for example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio


# We should somehow limit number of iterations for this coroutine.
# For example we can pass it as param 'tries':
@asyncio.coroutine
def print_time(number, loop, tries):
    et = loop.time() + 10.0
    for _ in range(tries):
        print('loop {} time {}'.format(number, datetime.now()))
        if (loop.time() >= et):
            break
        yield from asyncio.sleep(3)


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():

    # Run to tasks parallely and await both done using 'asyncio.gather':
    yield from asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.ensure_future(print_time(1, loop, tries=5)),
        asyncio.ensure_future(print_time(2, loop, tries=5))
    )


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Use 'run_until_complete' to finish execution when some coroutine is done:
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 15:16:03.864059
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 15:16:03.864059
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 15:16:06.864826
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 15:16:06.864826
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 15:16:09.865046
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 15:16:09.865046
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 15:16:12.865199
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 15:16:12.865199
loop 1 time 2017-06-11 15:16:15.865978
loop 2 time 2017-06-11 15:16:15.865978
[Finished in 12.2s]
```