# While loop blocks asyncio tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I've been using asyncio for a bit but I'm still fairly unfamiliar with it. My current issue is that while trying to wait for a response from a function with asyncio, the waiting (while loop) blocks the function from happening. Here is the code that sums up the problem:

```
import asyncio

response = 0

async def handle(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return x

async def run():
    global response
    for number in range(1, 21):
        response = await handle(number)
        print(response)
        if response == 10:
            await wait_for_next(response)

async def wait_for_next(x):
    while response == x:
        print('waiting',response,x)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('done')

tasks = [run()]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

wait_for_next is supposed to wait for the next response, but the while loop blocks the run() function. How could I stop this happening? Should I be using loop.run_in_executor, and if so, how?

(There were a couple of other examples of this I could find, but they were very specific and I didn't understand if our problems/solutions would be the same.)

Comment: I didn't use asyncio before, but I worked with async programming. the while loop will block the current thread, If you need execute a blocking functions you can use the run_in_executor() method of the EventLoop, this will be run the function in an executor.
loop.run_in_executor(executor=None, fn, *args)

Comment: It is blocked because there is nothing else to do. There is only one task to execute. May be add another task to tasks and the wait would be interleaved

Comment: Thanks @balki , it seems like adding another task allowed it to continue, so I'll have to split my run() task into seperate parts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already noted, loop stuck because `await wait_for_next(response)` blocks execution flow until this coroutine wouldn't be finished.

If you want some of your coroutines to be started without blocking execution flow you can start it as [asyncio.Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) about tasks) using `ensure_future` function:

```
import asyncio

response = 0

async def handle(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return x

async def run():
    global response
    for number in range(1, 21):
        response = await handle(number)
        print(response)
        if response == 10:

            # run wait_for_next "in background" instead of blocking flow:
            asyncio.ensure_future(wait_for_next(response))

async def wait_for_next(x):
    while response == x:
        print('waiting',response,x)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print('done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
waiting 10 10
11
12
13
14
done
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: This also works, thanks! Now I'll have to decide which correction benefits the program more 3:

Comment: Just remember to await on asyncio.sleep() in your background while loop, so other coroutines can be executed too.

Comment: Does not use `global` variable breaks the reason for using asyncio? 
I can set a `global` variable inside any loop and stop it without using asyncio.
Am I right? Maybe there are any other solutions?

Comment: PS: in Python 3.7+ use `create_task()` instead of `ensure_future()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task