# python3.6 async/await usage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, client, python-3.6

I’m working on a server/client program that , upon client signal, the server sends the client a series of messages, the series of messages through the function:

```
def messages():
    messages = [“first”, “second”, “third”, “fourth”]
    yield element
    time.sleep(10)
```

I’m trying to learn how to use python3.6 async to listen to for these messages, and check each second to see if another message has been received.

```
async def get_message(response): 
    async for element in response: 
        print (“got a message!”)
        print (element)
    else: 
        print (“no message received”)
```

However, when I run this, I get a runtime warning of coroutine ‘get_message” was never awaited. I don’t understand how “await” fits in here.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await) uses asyncio, but I don’t understand where I would be calling await asyncio(1) in my code? I’m only trying to modify the client side code, and it looks like in [PEP525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/), they put the await asyncio.sleep(delay) in what would be my server side code.

Edit:

Assuming that the server's messages are stored in response, I currently just call:

```
def run(): 
    get_message(response)
```

Comment: maybe `await` doesn't fit in your code ? maybe you should use it ?

Comment: I'm confused as to where I should use it - I put await asyncio.sleep(1) inside the function, but none of the error messages are printing. Sorry, I am quite new to this, so I might be missing something fundamental :(

Comment: coroutines are best used with IO, and need to be driven by an event loop. You don't use them like "regular" functions.