# How does the coroutine implement concurrency?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import asyncio,time

async def asleep(n):
    time.sleep(n)   # blocking method


async def doAsync(n):                        
    print("doAsync{} start...".format(n))
    await asleep(2)                             # case 1    
    #await asyncio.gather(asleep(2))            # case 2
    print("doAsync{} end...".format(n))
    #...                                     

tasks = [doAsync(i) for i in range(1,4)]
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(t) for t in tasks]


if __name__ == "__main__":                  
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()         
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
```

output:

```
## case 1 output        # No concurrency runs
doAsync1 start...       
(wait 2 seconds)
doAsync1 end...
doAsync2 start...
(wait 2 seconds)
doAsync2 end...
doAsync3 start...
(wait 2 seconds)
doAsync3 end...

## case 2 output        # Concurrency runs
doAsync1 start...
doAsync2 start...
doAsync3 start...
(wait 2*3 seconds)      
doAsync1 end...
doAsync2 end...
doAsync3 end...
```

case 1:

Although asleep() is also a coroutine,
But the doAsync isn't pending at "await asleep()"
doAsync does not implement concurrency

case 2:

doAsync is concurrent

The question：

1. How to explain how it works detail.
2. When should I use "await some_work()"  and when should I use "await   asyncio.gather(some_work)"

Answer (score 0):

Code you provided is not concurrent in both cases. It happens because of this line:

```
async def asleep(n):
    time.sleep(n)   # blocking method
```

`time.sleep` freezes asyncio event loop making it unable to process other running same time coroutines. You should never do such thing when using `asyncio` (if you want to run some blocking code inside coroutine, you should run it in another thread using `loop.run_in_executor` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207)).

To make your code coroutine working properly you should use special asyncio version of sleep that doesn't block event loop:

```
async def asleep(n):
    await asyncio.sleep(n)   # blocking method
```

Compare executing this version (in case1) with version you posted (in case1): 6 seconds vs. 2 seconds.

---

Once we creating [tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) from coroutines using ensure_future these coroutines start running concurently:

```
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(c) for c in coros]  # this run all coroutines concurently
```

Using `asyncio.gather` - is alternative way to run coroutines concurently:

```
await asyncio.gather(*coros)  # this run all coroutines concurently
```

---

Way `asyncio` works in detail may seem pretty complex. Best explanation I've seen: [David Beazley - Python Concurrency From the Ground Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4). Note, that you usually don't need to understand low-level detail to use `asyncio` on practice.

Comment: Thank you very much
I think my problem may not be concurrency and asynchrony, but the scheduling problem of the coroutine