# How to let nested function run async and not block the parent function

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous

```
def A(event):
   B(event)
   return "something"

def B(event)
   return event
```

Let's say I have a function like the one above, how do make function A return its output and not wait for function B. The output of A does not depend on function B but function B depends on the input of function A.

Comment: I don't think python-asyncio is a valid tag here? since it's supposed to be used for questions related to the library asyncio, not necessarily asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1):

In your example most easy way to do it is to run `B` in a thread. For example:

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)


def A():
    executor.submit(B)
    print("Hi from A")

def B():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Hi from B")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A()
```

If you want to do it using `asyncio`, you should wrap `A` and `B` to be [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) and use [asyncio.Task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207). Note however that unless `B` is I/O related it wouldn't be possible to make it coroutine without using thread. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33399896/1113207) more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your solution worked for me. Very grateful.