# How to async return from aiohttp server handler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am running a http server to handle slack API calls which arrive at the `events` endpoint. The slack documentation suggests that the app (this server) needs to acknowledge the receipt of the request within 3 seconds (which can be achieved by an empty body and status=200). My processing of the request takes way more than 3 seconds so I want to return immediately as soon as I receive the request with a blank response and then process the data. This is the code I am using:

```py
from aiohttp import web

routes = web.RouteTableDef()
app = web.Application()


async def process(data):
    # Do Some Processing which takes more than 5 seconds


@routes.post('/events')
async def handle_event(request):
    post_data = await request.json()
    await process(post_data)

    return web.Response(body="", status=200) 
    # I want to do this immediately then process() data afterwards

app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app, port=3000)
```

How do I return immediately and then process the data (which includes some database queries and sending a slack message using the API, too)

I tried creating a asyncio task but the return does not happen until this task finishes executing (which is understandable):

```py
    process_task = asyncio.create_task(process)
    await task
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Fire and forget" python async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await)

Comment: If you don't want to await the task, then don't `await task`.