# Achieve Fire and Forget in python and return from function before waiting for the result

Tags: python, asynchronous

In a Flask Application I am uploading a file to a server. I receive the file from a client that sends files sequentially. So to make the upload faster I wish to return a success response to the client as soon as I make the upload api request, without waiting for the response from the server.
I need to achieve asynchronous behaviour in my app similar to how node works.

What I need to be able to do is

```py
async def upload_file(f):
  result = await upload_api_call(f)
  ## do stuff based on result, in the background


def scp(data):
  file = data.file
  # upload file
  upload_file(f)
  # return success to client without waiting for upload to finish
  return 'success'
```

I have tried using asyncio and am able to get asynchronous behaviour. However the problem is I still cant send a return response to the client before the entire execution completes. This is because needing to use following at the end of scp function, before return.

```py
try:
  loop.run_forever()
finally:
  loop.close()
```

This nullifies my reason to wanting asynchronous behaviour as I am essentially waiting for the upload before returning to client.

Comment: please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await

Comment: Had checked that out. It doesnt answer how I can return without waiting for the result. In the selected answer loop.run_until_complete(main()) is being called. The flow continues after this only when all calls have ended execution.