# asyncio.create_task execute the coroutine immediately

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I watched an asyncio Pycon video on youtube where the presenter in one of her examples said she was using `asyncio.create_task` to run the coroutine instead of `await`, as `await` would block the execution of the coroutine until whatever it is awaiting is complete. I thought `asyncio.create_task` returns a `Task` which needs to be await. Nevertheless, I ran test using the following code and I am somewhat surprised by its result.

```
async def say_hello():
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("World")

async def run_coro(coro):
    asyncio.create_task(coro)

asyncio.run(run_coro(say_hello()))
```

The code above prints only `Hello`. I figured that `asyncio.create_task` in `run_coro` stops execution as soon as it reaches the `await` line in `say_hello`. If I rewrite `say_hello` as follows and the run it using `run_coro` I see all the lines before `await asyncio.sleep(0.5) printed on the terminal

```
async def say_hello():
    print("Hello")
    print("Hello")
    print("Hello")
    print("Hello")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    print("World")
```

If I rewrite `run_coro` as follows then all the lines get printed as expected:

```
async def run_coro(coro):
    asyncio.create_task(coro)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Can anyone tell why?

Answer (score 2):

Because

1. `asyncio.run` actually calls `loop.run_until_complete`, which means the main program will exit as soon as `run_coro` returns. So the scheduler does not have chance to run `say_hello`
2. `asyncio.create_task(coro)` runs `coro` [in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await)

if you change your code to

```
async def run_coro(coro):
    asyncio.create_task(coro)
    await asyncio.sleep(0.49)
```

coro actually only runs for 0.49 seconds, so you still can not see `print("World")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to suspend the current task by blocking coroutine or using `await` so that the next task can be done, which is why having `await asyncio.sleep(1)` work as expected. See more: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate?