# How to forcefully close an async generator?

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio

Let's say I have an async generator like this:

```py
async def event_publisher(connection, queue):
    while True:
        if not await connection.is_disconnected():
            event = await queue.get()
            yield event
        else:
            return
```

I consume it like this:

```py
published_events = event_publisher(connection, queue)
async for event in published_events:
    # do event processing here
```

It works just fine, however when the connection is disconnected and there is no new event published the `async for` will just wait forever, so ideally I would like to close the generator forcefully like this:

```py
if connection.is_disconnected():
    await published_events.aclose()
```

But I get the following error:

`RuntimeError: aclose(): asynchronous generator is already running`

Is there a way to stop processing of an already running generator?

Comment: Does the generator get stuck awaiting `queue.get()` if the disconnection happens just after `await connection.is_disconnected()`?

Comment: @DurandA yep, it's waiting for the next event to be added to the queue, that's why the generator is running, while I try to close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be related to [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue38559). Noticable:

> As shown in
>   https://gist.github.com/1st1/d9860cbf6fe2e5d243e695809aea674c, it's an
>   error to close a synchronous generator while it is being iterated.
>
> ...
>
> In 3.8, calling "aclose()" can crash with a RuntimeError.  It's no
>   longer possible to *reliably cancel* a running asynchrounous
>   generator.

Well, since we can't cancel running asynchrounous generator, let's try to [cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207) its running.

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import suppress


async def cancel_gen(agen):
    task = asyncio.create_task(agen.__anext__())
    task.cancel()
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task
    await agen.aclose()  # probably a good idea, 
                         # but if you'll be getting errors, try to comment this line
```

...

```
if connection.is_disconnected():
    await cancel_gen(published_events)
```

Can't test if it'll work since you didn't provide reproducable example.

Comment: Yep this was the workaround I was looking for. Actually `asyncio.create_task` gives the interface to have control over a `Future`. Thanks!

Comment: I get the same error when calling `loop.shutdown_asyncgens()`. Your answer suggests that with Python 3.8, `aclose()` cannot be called directly anymore, but `shutdown_asyncgens()` does call it. Does it mean that `shutdown_asyncgens()` doesn't work with Python 3.8 anymore?

Comment: Or does it mean that I should call `cancel()` on all the tasks before calling `shutdown_asyncgens()`? That's why I seem to understand from the discussion on the Python bugtracker... The thing is that in my case, I don't `create_task`, but I `ensure_future` for long (infinite) tasks. And I would like to stop them at some point.

Comment: It seems like it works: I do `task = ensure_future`, and then I `task.cancel()` before calling `shutdown_asyncgens()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout on the queue so `is_connected()` is polled regularly if there is no item to pop:

```py
async def event_publisher(connection, queue):
    while True:
        if not await connection.is_disconnected():
            try:
                event = await asyncio.wait_for(queue.get(), timeout=10.0)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                continue
            yield event
        else:
            return
```

Alternatively, it is possible to use [`Queue.get_nowait()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.get_nowait).

Comment: Yeah I wanted to do that, however it's not a plain `Queue` object, but one from `asyncio.queues` and doesn't receive a `timeout` parameter as an argument.

Comment: I did not realize I was not looking at the `asyncio.Queue` documentation. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah it solves my problem half way, however when I shut down the process, I would like to forcefully close the generator even if the connection is still alive.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Could your issue be related to this [Python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue32526)?

Comment: I'm using 3.8.0. This bug seems to be fixed, since my problem is that I get an exception and it's not closing the generator :D

Comment: Are you calling `published_events.aclose()` from another task? Can you share a minimal example code so we can reproduce your issue?