# breaking an async for loop with break in python

Tags: python, async-await, pyrogram

I have an asynchronous for loop and I would like to break it with an if statement. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-71' coro=<<async_generator_athrow without __name__>()>>
```

The code:

```
messages_iter = client.get_chat_history(config["chat_id"])

messages_list = []
message_count = 0
async for message in messages_iter: 
    if message_count == 5:
        break
     
     message_list.append(message)
     message_count += 1
```

Comment: This help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60233813/2357085