# Python Azure Function return response and continue function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure-functions

I am trying to get an Az Function to return an HTTP response and continue a background thread after. In the code below I try to use a thread but the response is still waiting for the function to finish before returning. Is there something I am missing?

```
import logging
import json
import threading
import azure.functions as func
from .commands import start_process


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    command = req.params.get('command')
    vm = req.params.get('vm')

    if not command:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            command = req_body.get('command')
            vm = req_body.get('vm')

    if command == 'restart':

        thread = threading.Thread(target=start_process(vm, command))
        thread.start()

    if command:
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {command}!")
else:
    return func.HttpResponse(
         "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
         status_code=400
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If a program is running Threads (that are not `daemon`), then the program will wait for those threads to complete before it terminates. Please follow [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#starting-a-thread) post for more information.

So, the AZ function (which is a stateless method) that you have created, will wait for the thread to complete as you have attempted to exit from the function by using a `return` statement. Hence the behavior that you see.

I think you need to look at `fire and forget` kind of thread execution, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await?noredirect=1&lq=1) SO question and answer should help in that.