# Fundamental logic of async / await functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await

Consider these two Python snippets:

```python
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await say_after(1, 'hello')
    await say_after(2, 'world')

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

and this one:

```python
import time


def say_after(delay, what):
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(what)


def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    say_after(1, "hello")
    say_after(2, "world")

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

main()
```

they produce exactly the same output, the flow of `main()` pauses after each function call.

So what's the difference between a synchronous flow and an asynchronous one in this example? And what's the point on using async/sync if the main flow is being paused / blocked?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you may find useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing multiple awaits will still only add a single await to the execution loop at a time.  You can use `await asyncio.gather` to add multiple awaits

```
async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await asyncio.gather(say_after(5, 'banana'), say_after(1, 'hello'), say_after(2, 'world'))
    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

would yield

```
started at 12:12:39
hello
world
banana
finished at 12:12:44
```

I am not an async expert but I have used this in the past to run off multiple lookups to systems etc

Comment: Extremely helpful, but I still don't understand what's the poing on executing something like I've illustrated in the first code snippet. If await blocks the code execution of the caller line, why bother declaring a function as an asynchronous function and calling it with await? Isn't that the same thing with executing a synchronous function call?

Comment: So without the `async` then a function cannot be called asynchronously at all.  `await` will tell Python to execute the function asynchronously, but Python can only do that as part of a `gather` or an event loop `asyncio.get_event_loop()` otherwise it just runs the one command async which is the same as sequential running.  Take a look at this https://stackabuse.com/python-async-await-tutorial/ I found it helpful when trying out async