# asyncio - Code is executing synchronously

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm a python beginner and taking from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iG6fr81xHKA&t=269s about the power of asyncio, I tried to use this example shown and repurpose it to execute 10 times. Here's a code snippet

```
def main(x):
    print("Hello")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("World!")
```

And so I tried to do it in a asyncio fashion however it doesn't execute asynchronously.
Here's so far what I've tried. What am I doing wrong?

```
import time
import asyncio


async def main(x):
    print(f"Starting Task {x}")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print(f"Finished Task {x}")


async def async_io():
    for i in range(10):
        await main(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(async_io())
    print(f"Took {time.perf_counter() - start_time} secs")
```

I've also tried to use queue_task in asyncio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `await`, by definition, waits for the task `main` to finish. So your code as-is is no different from the synchronous code you posted above. If you want to run them at the same time (asynchronously), while waiting for the results, you should use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) or [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) instead.

```
async def async_io():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        tasks += [main(i)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

If you don't care to wait for all of the `main()` calls to finish, you can also just use [`asyncio.create_task(main(i))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task), which creates a [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) object and schedule its execution in the background. In this case, `def async_io()` doesn't need to be async anymore.

Comment: How does the code work?

Comment: This saves all of the `main(i)` coroutines into a list (`tasks`), and `asyncio.gather` schedules all of the coroutines into the event loop and waits for it to finish then returns the result.

Comment: If you don't understand coroutines: Unlike normal functions that it executes the function body when you call the function, an async function returns a coroutine instead. Coroutines gets executed when you "await" for its execution or scheduled as a `Task` on the event loop. In my case, I awaited for `asyncio.gather()` which in turn creates `Task`'s for the list of coroutines (`tasks`), schedules them on the event loop and awaits for them to conclude.

Comment: Is there a good code example that demonstrates scheduling tasks like you mentioned (without asyncio.gather)?

Comment: Hmm maybe checkout the usage of create_task in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await