# Fire & Forget Asyncio

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I've been scouring the web to an answer to this question but I can't seem to find an actual answer or maybe i'm just missing it.

I'm trying to fire off a post request to start another microservice and I don't care what response comes back as that goes to a different part of my architecture

Once the request is sent I want to essentially continue the code a return this random json to where the function is called. For some reason whenever I use asyncio.run() it starts the send_requests() function but waits for it to respond before continuing.

Which is how async works i this case I think. But i'm unsure how to continue and exit the function before waiting for a response

Here's the pseudo code

```
Class DummyClass:
   def do_something():
       "doing something...."

       asyncio.run(send_requests) 

       return "random string"
       

   async def send_request():
         try:
            requests.post("send to url")
         except:
             raise Issue
```

I can use a decorator

```
def fire_and_forget(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

            if callable(f):
                return loop.run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise TypeError("Task must be a callable")

        return wrapped
```

which works fine but just wondering if we can do it without the decorator! I think I might be slightly misunderstanding asyncio

Thanks for any help.

I've been looking at ["Fire and forget" python async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await) but can't seem to work

Comment: Wouldn't `requests.post(..., timeout=0.1)` be sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is essentially `threading.Thread(target=requests.post, args=("send to url",)).start()` with lots of extra steps. And I think that's what you need here.

If you want to make it truly async (say you want to send hundreds of these without creating countless threads), you need to create async tasks and use `await` on a POST using an async library (e.g. httpx instead of requests). Those tasks then need to run in an event loop, which itself should be launched in a separate thread if you don't want the loop to block your main thread.

You seem to have some misconceptions about async: There's no async without event loop, and an event loop does not spawn in a separate thread. It does not jump around between arbitrary code, but only between Awaitables at predefined locations (`await`). If you can't `await` where you want your code to jump out, it's not async-compatible.

Comment: So if I just want to go do this function but not jump back out to the main function and continue then it's not async compatible? Since i'm creating an event loop to go do this function then I only have one thread still technically working? It's only the one request I want to send and once the function is called I don't care what it does just to know that it has been called? Thank you!

Comment: Your solution with `loop.run_in_executor` runs your code in an event loop (that has nothing to to but execute linearly) in a separate thread. So just use a separate thread without event loop then. The idea of an event loop is to interrupt/resume at `await` locations. This only works with code, that tells the event loop "I'm still waiting", i.e. Awaitable objects like calls to async functions. `requests.post` is not asynchronous. Neither is the code from which you are calling (and want to jump back to).