# Efficiently download files asynchronously with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-requests, requests-futures

I want to download files as fast as possible with python.Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
import os
import pathlib
from timeit import default_timer as timer


class AsyncDownloader:
    """Download files asynchronously"""

    __urls = set()
    __dest_path = None
    __user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'
    __read_timeout = 60
    __connection_timeout = 30
    __download_count = 0  # unlimited
    # http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network
    __worker_count = 17  # No of threads to spawn
    __chunk_size = 1024
    __download_time = -1
    __errors = []

    # TODO Fetch only content of a specific type from a csv
    # TODO Improve code structure so that it can be used as a commandline tool

    def set_source_csv(self, source_path, column_name):
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.column_name = column_name

        try:
            my_csv = pd.read_csv(source_path, usecols=[self.column_name], chunksize=10)
        except ValueError:
            print("The column name doesn't exist")
            return
        else:
            # No exception whatsoever
            for chunk in my_csv:
                AsyncDownloader.__urls.update(set(getattr(chunk, self.column_name)))

    def set_destination_path(self, dest_path):
        if dest_path.endswith('/'):
            dest_path = dest_path[:-1]
        self.dest_path = dest_path
        # TODO Add exception in case we can't create the directory
        pathlib.Path(self.dest_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        if os.access(self.dest_path, os.W_OK):
            AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(self.dest_path).resolve()

    def set_user_agent(self, useragent):
        self.useragent = useragent
        AsyncDownloader.__user_agent = self.useragent

    def set_connection_timeout(self, ctimeout_secs):
        self.timeout_secs = ctimeout_secs
        if self.timeout_secs >= 0:
            AsyncDownloader.__connection_timeout = self.timeout_secs

    def set_read_timeout(self, rtimeout_secs):
        self.timeout_secs = rtimeout_secs
        if self.timeout_secs >= 0:
            AsyncDownloader.__read_timeout = self.timeout_secs

    def set_download_count(self, file_count):
        self.file_count = file_count
        if self.file_count > 0:
            AsyncDownloader.__download_count = self.file_count

    def set_worker_count(self, worker_count):
        self.worker_count = worker_count
        if self.worker_count > 0:
            AsyncDownloader.__worker_count = self.worker_count

    def set_chunk_size(self, chunk_size):
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size
        if self.chunk_size > 0:
            AsyncDownloader.__chunk_size = self.chunk_size

    def print_urls(self):
        print(AsyncDownloader.__urls)

    def get_download_time(self):
        return AsyncDownloader.__download_time

    def get_errors(self):
        return AsyncDownloader.__errors

    def download(self):
        start = timer()
        try:
            session = FuturesSession(max_workers=AsyncDownloader.__worker_count)
            session.headers.update({'user-agent': AsyncDownloader.__user_agent})
            session.request(AsyncDownloader.__connection_timeout,
                            AsyncDownloader.__connection_timeout, stream=True)

            results = []
            # Give an accurate file count even if we don't have to download it as it a;ready exist
            file_count = 0

            for url in AsyncDownloader.__urls:
                filename = os.path.basename(url)
                # check if we need only a limited number of files
                if AsyncDownloader.__download_count != 0:
                    # No need to download file if it already exist
                    if pathlib.Path(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path / filename).is_file():
                        file_count += 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        if file_count < AsyncDownloader.__download_count:
                            file_count += 1
                            results.append(session.get(url))
                else:
                    if not pathlib.Path(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path / filename).is_file():
                        results.append(session.get(url))

            for result in results:
                # wait for the response to complete, if it hasn't already
                response = result.result()
                filename = os.path.basename(response.url)
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    with open(pathlib.Path(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path / filename).resolve(), 'wb') as fd:
                        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=AsyncDownloader.__chunk_size):
                            if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                                fd.write(chunk)

            end = timer()
            AsyncDownloader.__download_time = end - start

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            AsyncDownloader.__errors.append("Http Error:" + errh)
            # print("Http Error:", errh)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            AsyncDownloader.__errors.append("Error Connecting:" + errc)
            # print("Error Connecting:", errc)
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            AsyncDownloader.__errors.append("Timeout Error:" + errt)
            # print("Timeout Error:", errt)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            AsyncDownloader.__errors.append("OOps: Something Else" + err)
        else:
            return
```

The following code is making a very bad assumption.Indeed i am assuming that the first url will finish first which is of course not correct.

```
# wait for the response to complete, if it hasn't already
response = result.result()
```

How can i ensure that only requests that have been completed are processed instead of taking an assumption like above in an efficient manner ?

I would appreciate any other suggestion on how to improve performance.

Kind Regards

Comment: Why not just use solutions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests ?

Comment: btw having mutable variables as class variables is not a good idea

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if the connections were completed in order, you are still processing the files sequentially. The second file must wait for the first one to be written and so on. So, the best thing you can do is processing everything in parallel (this can be done despite the GIL, since io operations like writing to disk and reading from the network will release it). Basically, use regular `requests` library (not `requests-futures`) and create a future/thread per request + file-processing.

There are still more ways to make it faster, like keep downloading chunks while writing (i.e two threads, one for request and one for file-processing). And reading chunks in parallel by making `multi-part` requests, which is "download accelerator" territory and you may not want that kind of complexity in your code.

Edit: Also, chunked downloads are lazy, which means you are only making the initial requests in parallel, but the actual chunked-file download is being made sequentially, since it's being done in the main thread. So, your current approach is not much better than a *fully synchronous* one. The above advice still stands.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to do this doesn't require any threading or special async code: just use the regular `requests` library and its built-in streaming option. You say `response = session.get(url, stream=True)` and then use `response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)` (for example) to access the downloaded information one chunk at a time. Here's a functional example:

```
import requests
import os

def stream_multiple(urls):
    responses = {url: requests.get(url, stream=True) for url in urls)
    streams = {url: responses[url].iter_content(chunk_size=1024)
            for url in urls}
    handles = {url: open(os.path.basename(url), 'wb') for url in urls}
    while streams:
        for url in list(streams.keys()):
            try:
                chunk = next(streams[url])
                print("Received {} bytes for {}".format(len(chunk), url))
                handles[url].write(chunk)
            except StopIteration: # no more contenet
                handles[url].close()
                streams.pop(url)
```

Sample output:

```
rat@pandion:~/tmp$ python smu.py
Received 1296 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/files/9490/9490-0.txt
Received 1882 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21497.txt.utf-8
Received 1524 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1729/1729-0.txt
Received 1508 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21790.txt.utf-8
Received 1826 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/files/9490/9490-0.txt
Received 2349 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21497.txt.utf-8
Received 1834 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1729/1729-0.txt
Received 1838 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21790.txt.utf-8
Received 2009 bytes for http://www.gutenberg.org/files/9490/9490-0.txt
...
```

You could probably achieve slightly faster performance using threads or multiprocessing, but I doubt that would be significantly better. In virtually all cases writing your data to disk is going to be vastly faster than receiving it from the network.

Comment: *"slightly faster performance"* ? except in practice, servers limit their bandwidth. So, you may get about N times faster, where N is the number of files to download, by using threads.

Comment: If you're just benchmarking in a controlled environment where there is no network latency, packet loss, no bandwidth limits, etc, then sure, your sequential script must be fast.

Comment: The code I've given opens three simultaneous connections and gets data from them at the same time. You don't need threads to do that. And I would love to have no network latency to project gutenberg, but that's not where I live.

Comment: it does not. `next(streams[url])` is a blocking call that waits until one chunk is fully downloaded. `requests.get` is also blocking, it waits until the connection is made.

Comment: `next` blocks, yes, but that doesn't stop the other sockets from receiving data at the same time.

Comment: It does as soon as all buffers are full.

Comment: Well, I guess that didn't happen in my tests. Perhaps if you provide a solution we can do some benchmarks. I am curious.

Comment: to illustrate: say all downloads are fast, except one that's very slow (or even stall waiting to timeout). The slow one will stall all others while you call `next` on it. And that's just one possibility. Also, connecting (`requests.get`) may take any number of seconds.

Comment: *"...if you provide a solution..."* I've built a [download accelerator](https://github.com/nitely/ochDownloader) ages ago, been there done that.

Comment: I'm sure it's very nice, but it's hardly comparable to a several line proof of concept written in a few minutes. If one file is slow, it's simple to detect that and read smaller chunks from it or read from it less often. There's plenty of room for optimization. In any case, I still don't see any evidence for your claim that using threads can be "N times faster".

Answer (score 4):

To work with your code, I created a `.csv` file that contains links to several `robots.txt` files from several websites in this order: ***GitHub***, **UDemy**, **YouTube**.

After debugging, the first result in

```
response = result.result()
```

was *(In this order)*: ***UDemy***, ***YouTube***, ***GitHub***.
For the record, the size of each `robots.txt` is increasing in the same order that I got the results.
This means that there was no problem to begin with, despite me setting up a `.csv` file in a certain order, the results came in the order where the files were first downloaded.

> I would appreciate any other suggestion on how to improve performance.

As for performance, you can improve the speed by either creating a thread for writing the response to a file, or use an async IO library, such as [Tinche/aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles).

If you want to go even further, you could try improving the performance of the program itself by using an alternative implementation of Python, such as [PyPy](https://pypy.org/)

Comment: Thanks for clearing out my misunderstanding about the library.I am still new to python. Can you help me out to add aiofiles to write to a file asynchronously.Check https://pastebin.com/Ev47RYNG for my attempt.i get `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncDownloader.save_file' was never awaited
  AsyncDownloader.save_file(filename, response)`

Comment: No problem, luckily you're on a Q/A website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41790750/writing-files-asynchronously

Comment: I already seen this post and i can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code

Comment: To use coroutines, you'll have to create an event loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808893/how-to-use-async-await-in-python-3-5

Comment: Also, you are missing a `await fd.flush()` in line 94.

Comment: i got a bit tired i guess.Thanks for the help.New code is https://pastebin.com/ZasCSdz6 . The surprising thing is that async file IO made the operation slower( 5.4s  vs 3.7s earlier).What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you reached a conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gevent` if you don't worry about "monkey patch"

```
import gevent.monkey
import requests

CONNECTIONS = 10

gevent.monkey.patch_all()  # debug in PyCharm: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2012/08/gevent-debug-support/

import gevent.pool


def your_request_without_any_changes(url):
    return requests.get(url)


pool = gevent.pool.Pool(CONNECTIONS)
for response in pool.imap_unordered(your_request_without_any_changes, ['http://www.google.com'] * 100):
    print(response.status_code)
```

`gevent` use "event loop" and patch requests library (actually it happens at a lower level) for switching to another task when we are waiting for the response.